# UTF-8 urls must be uppercase or lowercase

Tags: url, utf-8, seo, case-sensitive

SEO sites suggest urls must be in lowercase for some reason, but my problem is with utf-8  urls can have some numbers and characters together, for example:

> %D9%F6

Which type is standard and better? This:

> %D9%F6

Or this:

> %d9%f6

I used lowercase, but when I copied the url and pasted it in the address bar, it became uppercase automatically, this case 301 redirect in my php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because encoded UTF8 should, by w3c and web standards, stay uppercase.
In google point of view it's the same, they put their encoded UTF8 word in uppercase.

Best standard is `%D9%F6` and you should stick to it !
Don't try lower or you should experience some duplicate page and for your seo it's really bad.

Comment: i think so, i changed my URL function to Upper case UTF-8 urls.